# ScrollTo on click not scrolling to the correct list item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scrolltop

I have an SVG map and a list where if you click on a plot number on the map it highlights on the list.

As there are quite a few items, when you click on a plot number on the map its supposed to scroll the list on the right to the correct item.

However as you start clicking around on all different numbers you can see the scroll breaks and it no longer scrolls to the correct number.

[Codepen here.](https://codepen.io/Probablybest/pen/GRmmqdE)

JS Code below:

```
$('.plot__list__item').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('selected');
    $('#' + $(this).data('map')).toggleClass('selected');
    $('#' + $(this).data('map')).siblings('g').removeClass('selected');
});

$('.plot__map__item').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).siblings('g').removeClass('selected');
    $('#' + $(this).data('list')).toggleClass('selected');
    $('#' + $(this).data('list')).siblings('li').removeClass('selected');
});

$('.plot__map__item').click(function () {
    let id = $(this).data('list');
    let scrollPos = $('#' + id).position().top;
    $('.plot__list').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPos
    }, 400);
});
```

Comment: You should take in consideration your current scroll position. If you scroll to the top before you click on any number, you will see that you are scrolled to the right place.

Comment: @DionisTakac how should I update the code so that it scrolls to the correct place without always having to scroll back to the top of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll position of the list will keep changing when you scroll it. Which is why you're getting irregular scrollpos. For example, when you initially click the 1 plot, the scrollpos will be 0. But when you scroll the list a bit it changes to a negative number and it will keep changing when you're scrolling the list.

To fix this, Calculate the top of your list and add the list's position to it. Change your click's animate function to:

```
scrollTop: $('.plot__list').scrollTop() + $('#' + id).position().top
```

Check [codepen here](https://codepen.io/albabameem/pen/NWjjbQg).

Comment: Happy to help, all the best @probablybest

Answer (score 0):

You should take in consideration your last scroll position. Try this code:

```
var currentPosition = 0;
$('.plot__map__item').click(function () {
    let id = $(this).data('list');
    let scrollPos = $('#' + id).position().top + currentPosition;
    currentPosition = scrollPos;
    $('.plot__list').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPos
    }, 400);
});
```

However, this solution will not work if you do scrolling without clicking on numbers. In that case you will need to recalculate your current position on scroll event.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but this creates the error: "Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Comment: I used Codepen you left, I changed it and it works good for me.

Comment: I didn't change anything related to call of top property.

Comment: @probablybest did you checkout my solution?